# Separador de palabras sin usar .split (python)

Tags: python

necesito hacer un separador de palabras en donde la funcion retorne las 3 palabras como variables distintas.
Hasta el momento tengo esto, lo cual solo retorna 1 de las 3 palabras:

```
def sep_palabras(palabras):
ini=0
k=0
while k<len(palabras):
    if palabras[k] =='-':
        palabra1= palabras[ini:k]
        return palabra1
        ini=k+1
        

    k+=1
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son *las 3 palabras* o cual es el caracter separador, el guión `-`? *Retornar las 3 palabras como variables distintas...* Python, distinto a la creecia popular, no retorna múltiples valores, retorna un arreglo, solo que si declaras igual cantidad de variables como valores que retorna la función, entonces se desempaca cada valor en cada variable respectiva.

Comment: las 3 palabras pueden ser cualquier que el usuario escriba. El carácter separador, en efecto es el guion.

Comment: aeportugal ya te dió la respuesta. Tu función tiene que devolver un arreglo con las 3 palabras. Igual que lo haría el `split`

Answer (score 0):

Tu función solo retorna una palabra porque se encuentra con un `return` dentro de un ciclo que aún no termina.

[1] También hay otro problema *oculto*, y es que cuando se llegue al último elemento de las palabras, no se va a encontrar el separador, por lo que ya no va a entrar al `if` y por ende no va a retornar la última palabra.

Entonces para corregirlo, y para [medio simular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.split) el `.split` de Python, el separador por defecto es `' '`, pero le puedes enviar uno personalizado:

```
def sep_palabras(palabras, sep=' '):
    lista = []
    p = ''
    for c in palabras:
        if c != sep:
            p += c
        else:
            lista.append(p)
            p = ''
    lista.append(p) # [1] Agrega la última palabra
    return lista

print(sep_palabras("")) # ''
print(sep_palabras("Hola-mundo", '-')) # ['Hola', 'mundo']
print(sep_palabras("Una frase de prueba")) # ['Una', 'frase', 'de', 'prueba']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Otra versión del separador, algoritmo nada original]

Se recorre el texto buscando el caracter separador. Cada vez que se encuentra uno, se copia el texto desde el separador anterior (o desde el comienzo) y se agrega a una lista de salida.

Cuando se termina el texto, todavía queda una palabra pendiente por copiar.

```
def separar(texto, separador):
    resultado = []
    inicio = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[i] == separador:
            resultado.append(texto[inicio:i])
            inicio = i + 1
    i += 1
    resultado.append(texto[inicio:i])
    return resultado
```

#### Demo

Para facilitar la validación, probe los mismos textos contra el resultado dado por `split`.

```
tests = [
    "",
    "a",
    "a b",
    "a-b",
    "a--b",
    "-",
    "--",
    "-a-",
    "Las-Tres-Palabras son las tres palabras"]

for test in tests:
    print("Test:", test)
    print("--> separ:", separar(test, "-"))
    print("--> split:", test.split("-"))
```

produce:

```
Test: 
--> separ: ['']
--> split: ['']
Test: a
--> separ: ['a']
--> split: ['a']
Test: a b
--> separ: ['a b']
--> split: ['a b']
Test: a-b
--> separ: ['a', 'b']
--> split: ['a', 'b']
Test: a--b
--> separ: ['a', '', 'b']
--> split: ['a', '', 'b']
Test: -
--> separ: ['', '']
--> split: ['', '']
Test: --
--> separ: ['', '', '']
--> split: ['', '', '']
Test: -a-
--> separ: ['', 'a', '']
--> split: ['', 'a', '']
Test: Las-Tres-Palabras son las tres palabras
--> separ: ['Las', 'Tres', 'Palabras son las tres palabras']
--> split: ['Las', 'Tres', 'Palabras son las tres palabras']

Process finished with exit code 0
```